# Changing strings with no decimals to have .0 at the end

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, string

I have a points layer with a `"Name"` column.

The `"Name"` values are strings and similar to

```
'X501', 'X501.1', and 'X501.2'.
```

I need to change any values like `'X501'` to `'X501.0'` and leave others as they are.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sound like a pure Python issue, testing for strings that don't contain a '.' and appending a ".0"

Comment: I tried various forms of the following but clearly don't know the syntax well enough.

IF ('Line' contains ".", "Line", "Line"&"0.0")

Comment: Ok think I'm getting closer... 

IF ("Line" LIKE '%.%', "Line", "Line"+".0") almost works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out just now, this works perfectly:

```
IF ("Line" LIKE '%.%', "Line", concat("Line",'.0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these expressions:

```
if("Name"='X501','X501.0',"Name")
```

or

```
if(regexp_match("Name",'^X501$'),'X501.0',"Name")
```

---

**References:**

- [Regular-Expressions.info | Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I need something that works for multiple entries and different numbers, not just 'X501'... so maybe numeric wildcards or similar